# Im stuck in RHEL 6.3

Tags: shell, scripting, rhel

What about ??

```
if -f $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP del $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP

else
 echo Event Log Backup Module not Activated.
fi;
```

Is there any mistakes?

Comment: Do you really have a command called "-f" on your system?

Comment: I found it on the internet ..

Comment: So , do i need to change the "-f" ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

```
if [ -f $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP ]
then
  rm $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP
else
  echo "Event Log Backup Module not Activated."
fi
```